# Angular - Manual triggering binding

Tags: javascript

I have the following markup

```
 <span>{{ prop }}</span><input type="text" ng-model="prop" />
```

I want the span content to be updated manually and not upon each key stroke.

Is there a way to tell angular, stop the binding and when i want to apply it again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just make another property and bind input to it, like

```
<span>{{ prop }}</span><input type="text" ng-model="propDraft" />
```

then whenever you need in your javascript do

```
prop = propDraft
```

Comment: i already use this solution. i want to know if i can control the binding manually

Comment: To my knowledge - there is no built-in features for that. The only thing to control binding I know is `::` operator, which instructs angular to bind value only once.

Answer (score 0):

If you need not to bind the span content to the input field, maybe you could simply use a function trigged by the onChange event.

```
<span id="prop"></span><input type="text" onChange="document.getElementById('prop').innerHTML = this.value" />
```